# Обновление страницы и angular-ui-router

Tags: .htaccess, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Приложение на angular  размещено в одном из каталогов основного сайта: `http:\\сайт\app`

В HTML коде установлен  тег: `<base href="/app">`

В проекте используется angular-ui-router c состояниями вида:

```
.state('auth_cab.listPapers', {
    url: '/listPapers',
    templateUrl: 'views/listPapers.html',
    controller:'PaperController'
})
```

Установлен режим: `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Если пользователь обновляет страницу по следующему адресу, то он попадает на ошибку 404: `http:\\сайт\app\authcab\listPapers`

*.htaccess* в папке *app* (должен отдавать файлы, остальное переадресовывать на `http:\\сайт\app\index.html`, а точнее на  `http:\\сайт\app\authcab\listPapers` в данном случае).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/

RewriteCond     %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|img|css|js|jpg|gif|jpeg)
RewriteRule     ^(.+) index.html [L]
```

Если не использовать вложенный каталог *app* для приложения, то с соответствующей заменой всё работает.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить приложение на работу во вложенном каталоге *app*.

Comment: Не используйте цитирование для частей кода и подобного, лучше использовать обрамление кавычками: `   `

Comment: Спасибо, не буду )

Comment: @AivanF., урлы стоило оставить цитатами, кроме того в инлайновых кусках кода нет подсветки, поэтому часть с `base` стоило сделать блоком кода.

Comment: @Grundy 0k, учту в дальнейшем.